# Why does this relay oscillate? How can I stop it?

Tags: batteries, charger

I'm having fun with a simple auto cut off circuit for a battery charger. This is the diagram. I found it on the web:

[image]

The problem comes when trying to set the cut off voltage by fiddling with VR1, and also happens when the battery is about to be ready for disconnection: when adjusting VR1, if I try to fine tune it, say, rotate it "very slow" until LEDs swaps, relay RL1 starts to oscillate fast for a long time without actually falling into the battery disconnection mode. It just sits there buzzing, no matter if I try it with or without the battery connected. On the website they say:

> The adjustment is done by the 10k preset, and a multimeter connected with the output terminals that go to the battery.

For power supply, I'm using a modified UPS transformer. It came with two 6V secondary coils in parallel, so I put them in series to get 12V and attached a full wave rectifier module.

In fact, I have tried some variations of that "concept", and all of the have the same problem.

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to the comments and answers (kudos to Math Keeps Me Busy) I got this working. *Basically I added a bigger capacitor to the rectifier output.*

**Note:** I forgot to say it earlier, this is for acid/lead batteries, old school ones without any electronics inside, and not sealed or gel.

[image]

Comment: Your power supply isn't DC, but pulsed DC. This may not be what you want, since it will drop to 0v periodically.

Comment: @rsaxvc adding a 78xx-based regulator with an external power transistor to assume more than 1A would suffice?

Comment: No. You probably need a smoothing capacitor. See my answer.

Comment: HINT: A battery charger will either use a dedicated IC, or have several active components like op-amps, a voltage reference, etc. The circuit shown would, if it was working to begin with, only be good to charge a supercapacitor, or a lead-acid battery. It would happily destroy most other cells - probably setting your house on fire as well. If you see a big watermark across the circuit: run away. None of that junk ever works as desired, or is practical, or is correctly described, etc. It's nonsense propagated by people who don't have a clue. Don't learn from the clueless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As for power supply, I'm using a modified UPS transformer, it came with two 6V secondary coils in parallel, so I put then in series to get 12V, and attached a full wave rectifier module.

As @rsaxvc points out the voltage from your power supply pulsates from 0 to a peak and then back down to zero. It is quite likely that is the source of your relay oscillating. (There is another possibility, which I will also consider.) What your circuit needs is a "smoothing" capacitor connected across the DC outputs of your rectifier bridge. Typically, this smoothing capacitor will be a fairly high value electrolytic capacitor. (Electrolytic capacitors are usually polarized, so it is important to connect the positive lead of the capacitor to the positive output of the rectifier bridge.)

There is another potential problem with your circuit. It has no hysteresis to speak of. You may have noticed that a thermostat turns a heater on at one temperature, and turns it off at a slightly different temperature. This feature is called hysteresis. If the thermostat turned on and off at exactly the same temperature, then very tiny deviations above or below that temperature will cause the thermostat to turn on or turn off the heater. We call any unwanted, but unavoidable deviations in some value "noise". Without hysteresis, even low amplitude noise can cause the output of a switching circuit to oscillate in an undesired fashion, when the input is very close to the tripping point of the circuit. The solution to such a problem is to add hysteresis to the system. In the case of an electrical system, a Schmitt trigger is a kind of circuit that can be used to provide hysteresis.

Although your circuit does not have hysteresis to speak of, I lean strongly toward believing that @rsaxvc is correct, and the problem is due to your supply not having a smoothing capacitor.

Addendum: While I focused on the cause of your relay "buzzing", I concur completely with @Kuba that your circuit is not appropriate for charging batteries. Kuba is correct that it could be downright dangerous to use such a circuit for charging batteries.

Comment: I thought this circuit was being used with a purpose-built battery charger as the input, and was only meant to disconnect the battery when it was fully charged as sensed by the circuit. But even that is badly flawed, using the B-E junction as a voltage reference. And the output diode would interfere with an external battery charger's voltage sensing circuit. As for hysteresis, a DC relay already exhibits hysteresis, where dropout voltage is much lower than pull-in voltage, but it would still need a fairly smooth DC as supplied from a capacitor.

Comment: @PStechPaul you are correct that the relay has hysteresis. However, as I see it, it is Vbe of the transistor that determines whether the relay is on or off. If I am not mistaken, at room temperature, a change of Vbe by about 18 mV will double Ic. Magnify this by 12V/0.7V gives about 300 mV change in input voltage will double (or halve) the current through the relay coil. That is some hysteresis, but not alot. Maybe I made a mistake in my thinking or calculations?

Comment: If the input is current limited, when the battery load is disconnected, the input voltage will increase, and that will also provide some hysteresis that will increase the current into the relay coil.

Answer (score 1):

There is a strong correlation between a circuit diagram having a big watermark plastered on the front of it, and the circuit it represents being someone's fantasy and not much more. This is the case here. The circuit is not nonsense, because it tries to implement some nebulous idea of a charger, but it doesn't work and can't work as shown and that's that. It's also, in most cases, a device apt to set your house on fire and I'm not joking. If you use it with a lithium-ion cell or battery, that's a very likely outcome. **DO NOT USE SUCH CIRCUITS!**.

1. The power supply is lost if the battery is a cell that can be safely fully discharged - like NiCd or NiMh, or is a deeply discharged cell for any other reason - or shorted.
2. Due to (1), it needs an auxiliary power supply.
3. It has no hysteresis and thus oscillates.
4. The voltage regulation accuracy is poor enough to shorten the life of cells or outright damage them.

The circuit uses a crude single-transistor low-gain comparator with no hysteresis to speak of. That's what makes it oscillate.

The relay is a bit costlier than a semiconductor switch, but since you already got it, we may as well make the thing work with it. It still only crudely demonstrates the concept, and it's not a usable battery charger. It can charge capacitors safely, if you limit the current appropriately, and that's... about it. A teaching aid, but **not** a battery charger!

Even to make this crude demonstrator work at all, we need a voltage reference that's a bit better than a transistor V(BE) voltage, and a comparator that's a bit better than a single transistor.

TL431 is the cheap and easy solution to this problem. They are easy to find - even just from junk switching power supplies - and will do all that's needed here - *to make the very original circuit work at all*. **That doesn't mean you have a usable charger**, since the original design completely missed the mark in that respect. It will *merely* make the circuit do something that was imagined its function would be - even though that's not how you would charge batteries. A supercapacitor - sure. Batteries - a big nope on that.

The circuit behavior will be independent of the input voltage, too: the relay action will depend solely on battery voltage as compared to a relatively stable reference voltage inside of the TL431, and nothing else.

We also need *two* power supplies:

1. The supply that is current-controlled (limited) and charges the capacitor ("battery") and has no other function.
2. The supply that keeps our circuit working - it must be independent of the first supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkrIjg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The dashed-line boxes are just simulation models for - on the left - the current-limited power supply, and - on the right - the TL431 3-pin chip.

R3 provides the necessary hystereis. The relay is a 5V or 6V type.

Still, this is an extremely crude kind of a charger, since it only controls cell voltage. It will destroy lithium cells, for example. **DO NOT USE ON LITHIUM CELLS!**.

A lithium cell charger needs to be a CV/CC supply - like a lab power supply, pretty much - with a charge termination circuit when the charge current falls below 3% of the rated charge current. [See Battery University for further details](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-409-charging-lithium-ion).

Thus, such a charger requires not only a CC/CV supply, but also a charge termination circuit, and a restart function that restarts the charge - using a pushbutton, a timer, a battery disconnect detector, etc.

It is of course possible to make such a charger and have it reasonably perform using fairly cheap and simple components, but it's much simpler to just use a dedicated charging module that uses an IC dedicated for that purpose, that includes necessary cell protection functionality.

A minimum discrete solution for a Li-Ion cell would need a voltage reference (e.g. TL431), a CC/CV linear supply (2 op-amps), an end-of-charge detector, a flip-flop (e.g. an SCR) to latch the end-of-charge state, and a pushbutton to start the charge process.